# Automatically detect and remove http:// from input using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one/many HTML `input`s that are to be used for URL entry

```
<input></input>
<input></input>
```

What I would like is: When an entry is made, then `http://` is stripped from the beginning of that input. For example if `http://google.com` is entered then it becomes `google.com` in the input instead.

How does one go about achieving this with Javascript (or jQuery)? I haven't tried anything because I don't know where to begin. Pointers to documentation and/or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Get `string` from `input` on `change` then `string.replace(/* regexp begins http:// */, '')` and write back to `input`

Comment: Yes, I have tried and I was looking for it and I just had bad luck. No idea why I got so much bad reputation for the simple question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the value of the input and use regexp to replace `http://` from the value.

```
$('input').change( function() {
    var input = $('input');
    input.val(
        $('input').val().replace(/https?:\/\//gi,'')
    );
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/spedwards/983uN/)

**UPDATE**

[Xotic750](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592253/xotic750) has a fiddle with 6 different methods for removing `http://`
http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/kyKsK/
I also updated my code to support the possibility of `https://` as well.

Comment: It'd be nice if people were to comment on why they downvote a perfect answer?

Comment: `perfect answer`??? `$('input')` used 3 times, replace does does not remove `http://` from the start of the string only (which one assumes that the OP wants). Seems a pretty poor answer to an already poor question. Answer uses jQuery when not specified anywhere in question, and no Javascript example.

Comment: `JavaScript (not to be confused with Java) is a dynamically-typed language commonly used for client-side scripting. Use this tag for questions regarding ECMAScript and its dialects/implementations (excluding ActionScript). Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript ...`

Comment: No need to be a hardass but it does remove `http://` as the OP asked for.

Comment: You did ask, I gave you an answer. Would you have preferred that I didn't and that you could continue to wonder about your `perfect answer`?

Comment: Think of it this way, if you delete this answer then you are going to get a badge from it. Bonus, huh!?

Comment: @Xotic750 Thank you for your smartness, you are the best, Xotic750. :) I've just asked and just got the working answer. Seems the stackoverflow is getting worst because of that kind of people like you who thinks you are so smart that this kind of question is stupid. Think about beginners smarta**.:)

Comment: @Simon Before throwing mud in my face, take the time to check my answers and see that I have been around for some time, helping beginners like yourself. Speedwards wanted to know why his answer was being down-voted, again I took the time to help with an answer: the probability being that his answer was under par and that he ignored a primary rule in this forum. It's people like you that make me wonder why I, or others, bother to take the time to help. So take a look in the mirror and ask yourself, before posting such drivel: how smart am I looking?

Comment: @Xotic750 Too be fair I thought it was tagged with jQuery.

Comment: @Speedwards Fine, but once you know then it is recommended that you either delete the answer or go back and improve it. Let's have a look at some possible improvements as the answer was accepted. http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/kyKsK/

Comment: @Xotic750 I am sorry about that and thank you for fixing the question.