# Form Post not taking links

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post, hyperlink

I got a post form and the issue is that It errors when I try to post a link like https://www.google.com/ into an imput type text, It akts as some command I do not understand, anyway heres my code and let me know what exactly is wrong.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
$animeid = $_POST['animeid'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$code = $_POST['code'];
echo $animeid;
echo $number;
echo $code;
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<br>
<input class="inputs" placeholder="Link" name="code" type="text" id="code">
</br>
<br>
<input class="inputs" placeholder="ID" name="id" type="number" id="id">
</br>
<br>
<input class="inputs" placeholder="Number" name="number" type="number" id="number">
</br>
<br>
<center><input class="btnExample" name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Add Episode!"></center>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And its a simple thing really If Id to type anything other than a link it would work but I need it to be a link and thats that , I still can't see why from dosen't post links and Id like to know how can I make it post links.!

OK I think I know how to solve It But Only Know How To I will really need help on it as I did not learn javascript but There should be a way to remove the http:// or https:// before Posting The FORM And then Ill reADD it in the PhP but Now What I got To Figure It Is How Can I make a javascript that will autoremove http:// or https:// Before posting The FORM , Thanks for the Answers You Gave Me Till Now , I will apriciate If SOmeone Will Know How to autoremove words with javascript Thanks !

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: `<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>` --> `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`

Comment: we all start somewhere

Comment: It redirects me to my hosting company or so :!

Comment: Oh I see :) That might Acualy be It Let ME Give It A Try :P

Comment: Nope Still Errors :!

Comment: I do not recommend you to use your template as the code engine (kind of controller). That goes totally against the MVC principle. It's much harder to code

Comment: Well My Template Might Be Hard To Understand But Thats Ok Because I created Every Bit In it So Im FIne With The way it looks , WHat I Really Wonder Is That Javascript That will answer My Question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically detect and remove http:// from input using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115150/automatically-detect-and-remove-http-from-input-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Its Simple , I Figured that Links act as A Code that wants to be posted to so what acutally happens when You Post it Its Simple Instead of Posting It To http://anime4life.net/ it Posted It To http:// linkthatIinitiallyTypedIntheInput+anime4life.net which caused to have a very long and unsucessful end
Well The Solution Is Simple , First AutoRemove The http:// straight as Im TYping Using JsQuery Like This

```js
$('input').change( function() {
    var input = $('input');
    input.val(
        $('input').val().replace(/https?:\/\//gi,'')
    );
});
```

And Then That Posts The Form 
Next in the echo Use This

```html
<?PHP
echo "https://".$_POST['code']."";
```

And That Puts It Back For The Display , Well Thankyou All For Trying To Help!

Answer (score 1):

Action is where you're sending the data to get posted (i.e. #) for same page

You need to run a set check on each variable.  i.e.:

```
if (isset($_POST['fromPerson']){
     $fromPerson=$_POST['fromPerson'];
}
```

Comment: Hmh, so In My case I write 
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
$add= $_POST['add'];
}
But then where do I place the Code Before the } :?

Comment: No, you check if each variable is being sent then do a ($var1 && $var2...) then run the data.  `add` isn't required for anything to be ran, but the variables that are being ran need to be checked for.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
```

in

```
<form method="post" action="?">
```

and change

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
$animeid = $_POST['animeid'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$code = $_POST['code'];
echo $animeid;
echo $number;
echo $code;
}
?>
```

in

```
<?php
 echo (isset($_POST['animeid'])) ? $_POST['animeid'] : '';
 echo (isset($_POST['number']))  ? $_POST['number']  : '';
 echo (isset($_POST['code']))    ? $_POST['code']    : '';
?>
```

your code

```
<?php
 echo (isset($_POST['animeid'])) ? $_POST['animeid'] : '';
 echo (isset($_POST['number']))  ? $_POST['number']  : '';
 echo (isset($_POST['code']))    ? $_POST['code']    : '';
?>
<form method="post" action="?">
<table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<br>
<input class="inputs" placeholder="Link" name="code" type="text" id="code">
</br>
<br>
<input class="inputs" placeholder="ID" name="id" type="number" id="id">
</br>
<br>
<input class="inputs" placeholder="Number" name="number" type="number" id="number">
</br>
<br>
<center><input class="btnExample" name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Add Episode!"></center>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: try `<form method="post" action="?">`

Comment: I did try and It came as an error but when I didnt Use The http:// it redirected to my homepagewith? at the end

Comment: But heres what I think , If There would be a javascript that can autoremove The http:// or https:// then Backinto php I can readd it no problem but Now I got TO Find A Script that would remove the http:// before even Posting it and I know not javascript